How to model a factory with batch production and stock checks using SimPy?
I am working on modeling a shoe factory and simulating its operations using SimPy. My goal is to create different scenarios and identify the optimal factory layout for a new facility. This is my first time using SimPy, and while I have read through the documentation, I am struggling to implement some key aspects of the simulation.
What I am trying to do

The factory generates batch orders at random intervals of time.
Orders can be one of two categories: Make To Order (MTO) and Make To Stock (MTS).

For MTO orders, they are automatically sent to the production queue and then to expedition.
For MTS orders, a check is made to see if items are already in stock:

If available, items are immediately sent to expedition.
If not, the order goes to production and then to stock.


At the beginning of each day, a check is made for items that left the stock the previous day. These items should be sent to production and then restocked.


There are 4 machines in 1 production line. Production is continuous: as soon as item #1 leaves machine #1, item #2 enters machine #1, and item #1 moves to machine #2, and so on.
In the first simulation, there will be only 1 production line.
Machines require setup time for each new batch:

If the products in batch #2 differ from batch #1, each machine needs setup time before starting.
Ideally, machines should be set up independently: once machine #1 finishes batch #1, it enters setup for batch #2. Machine #2 does the same once it finishes processing its batch, and so on.



What I managed to do
So far, the model does the following:

Creates 4 machines
Creates 1 production line
Creates 2 batches of products
Randomly generates a number of products

The 4 machines are part of the production line. Products are randomly distributed between the batches. The batches enter the production line queue, and once a batch is in the production line, its items are fed into the queues of the machines. When the last item from a batch exits the last machine in the production line, the next batch is allowed to enter the production line.
Limitations

Batch processing issue: For example, if batch #1 has 2 products, product #2 can only enter machine #1 after product #1 has passed through the last machine. Ideally, product #2 should enter machine #1 as soon as product #1 leaves it.
Incorrect setup time: Setup time is being calculated incorrectly. Batches are created with timestamps. Suppose batch #2 is created at timestamp = 5, and batch #1 finishes processing at t = 6. If the setup time is 2, the next batch should start processing at t = 8, but it incorrectly starts at t = 7.
Dynamic setup timing issue: I can't implement the setup time dynamically. That is, a machine should enter setup mode as soon as there are no items from the current batch in the previous machine's queue. For example, machine #2 should start setup as soon as there are no items from the current batch in machine #1’s queue or in its own queue.
No stock system: There is currently no stock management in place.
No order differentiation: There is no system to differentiate between MTO and MTS orders.

Here is the code I've written so far. I'm not tied to this implementation and would welcome a complete refactor if it leads to a more efficient or standard approach.
# Simulation parameters and machine configurations
RANDOM_SEED = 68
SIM_TIME = 100

NUM_PRODUCTS_MEAN = 5
NUM_PRODUCTS_SIGMA = 3

TIME_BETWEEN_BATCHES = 5

NUMBER_OF_MACHINES = 4

MACHINE_PARAMS = {
    1: {'mean': 0.5, 'sigma': 1.0},
    2: {'mean': 3.0, 'sigma': 0.5},
    3: {'mean': 1.5, 'sigma': 0.3},
    4: {'mean': 0.5, 'sigma': 0.1},
}


# Function to calculate time per part based on the machine type
def time_per_part(machine):
    machine_id = machine.capacity

    if machine_id not in MACHINE_PARAMS:
        raise ValueError(f"Invalid machine {machine_id}. Must be one of {list(MACHINE_PARAMS.keys())}")

    PT_MEAN = MACHINE_PARAMS[machine_id]['mean']
    PT_SIGMA = MACHINE_PARAMS[machine_id]['sigma']

    t = random.normalvariate(PT_MEAN, PT_SIGMA)
    while t <= 0:
        t = random.normalvariate(PT_MEAN, PT_SIGMA)

    return t


# Machine class definition
class Machine:
    def __init__(self, env, name, capacity):
        self.env = env
        self.name = name
        self.capacity = capacity


# Product class representing individual products in the batch
class Product:
    def __init__(self, env, name, category, sku):
        self.env = env
        self.name = name
        self.category = category
        self.sku = sku

    def assemble(self, ms):
        for machine_id in range(1, NUMBER_OF_MACHINES + 1):
            machine = yield ms.get(lambda m: m.capacity == machine_id)
            print(f'{self.name} is being assembled by {machine.name} at {self.env.now}')
            yield self.env.timeout(time_per_part(machine))
            yield ms.put(machine)
            print(f'{self.name} is done with {machine.name} at {self.env.now}')


# Batch generator to create and process batches of products
def batch_generator(env, pl, ms, skus, queue):
    for sku in skus:
        num_products = int(random.normalvariate(NUM_PRODUCTS_MEAN, NUM_PRODUCTS_SIGMA))
        num_products = max(1, num_products)
        batch = Batch(env, f'Batch_{sku}', 'category', sku, num_products)
        env.process(batch.process_batch(pl, ms, queue))
        queue.append(batch.name)
        print(f'Batch {batch.name} is ready at {env.now}')
        yield env.timeout(TIME_BETWEEN_BATCHES)


# Batch class to handle the processing of products
class Batch:
    def __init__(self, env, name, category, sku, num_products):
        self.env = env
        self.name = name
        self.category = category
        self.sku = sku
        self.num_products = num_products
        self.products = [Product(env, f'Product_{sku}_{i}', category, sku) for i in range(num_products)]

    def process_batch(self, pl, ms, queue):
        if len(queue) > 1 and queue[len(queue)-2] != self.name:
            setup_time = random.uniform(1, 3)
            print(f'Setup time of {setup_time} before processing next batch at {self.env.now}')
            yield env.timeout(setup_time)
        
        yield pl.get()
        print(f'Batch {self.name} is being processed by {pl.name} at {self.env.now}')

        for i, product in enumerate(self.products):
            print(f'Processing {product.name} from Batch {self.name} (Product {i+1}/{self.num_products})')
            yield self.env.process(product.assemble(ms))
            print(f'{product.name} from Batch {self.name} is done processing at {self.env.now}')
        
        print(f'Batch {self.name} is done processing at {self.env.now}')
        yield pl.put()


# ProductionLine class for managing the production line
class ProductionLine:
    def __init__(self, env, name, capacity):
        self.env = env
        self.name = name
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.lines = simpy.FilterStore(env, capacity=capacity)

        for i in range(capacity):
            self.lines.put(self)

    def get(self):
        return self.lines.get()

    def put(self):
        return self.lines.put()


# Setting up the simulation environment and running it
print('Machine shop')
random.seed(RANDOM_SEED)

env = simpy.Environment()

machine_1 = Machine(env, "Machine_1", 1)
machine_2 = Machine(env, "Machine_2", 2)
machine_3 = Machine(env, "Machine_3", 3)
machine_4 = Machine(env, "Machine_4", 4)

machine_shop = simpy.FilterStore(env, capacity=NUMBER_OF_MACHINES)
machine_shop.items = [machine_1, machine_2, machine_3, machine_4]

pl = ProductionLine(env, 'Main Line', capacity=1)

skus = ['SKU1', 'SKU2']
batch_queue = []

env.process(batch_generator(env, pl, machine_shop, skus, batch_queue))

env.run(until=SIM_TIME)

Thank you in advance to anyone who takes the time to read through all of this and help me out! I really appreciate it.

This is way out of scope for SO. SymPy is not the tool you want - you need an OR solver like OR Tools, pyomo, PuLP or custom heuristics

I'd also say that they don't typically work well with continuous processes. I have an example on my website (www.jpilkington.com) for manufacturing but it's super-simplistic for demo purposes. The code is also massively outdated but it supports a number of things you're trying to do, even if not implemented. Shameless promotion, sorry, but this is my gig

Hey, @roganjosh. Thanks for the comment and no worries about the self promotion haha. I might have misspoken when I mentioned "continuous process". The simulation should model discrete production of shoes, where each item moves from machine #1 to machine #2, and so on.  I will probably edit the question to reflect this.
Also, this is for Uni and the professor has constrained us to use SimPy for the simulation. I feel like there is a way to do it, but my experience is still fairly limited. I will keep experimenting with it, just hoped someone could point me in the right path.

I'm a bit busy to really look at this, but why not start with a simple 4 machine assemble line where there is no queues between machines.  So machine 1 is not "done" until machine 2 is available.  And machine 2 is not "done" until machine 3 is available, ect..  Which means if machine 3 is taking a extra long time it will block machine 1 and 2 from finishing and advancing the products to the next machines.

Hey @Michael, thanks for the input. Also, I've sent you an email.

Here is a sim of a 4 machine line with no accumulating queues.  This addresses the issue of how machine 1 does not start up right away after finishing a product
"""
simple assemble line with no queues between machines.
so if the last machine takes a long time it blocks the line from advancing

Programmer: Michael R. Gibbs
"""

import simpy

class Prod():
    """
    sipmple class with unque ids
    """
    next_id = 1
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = self.__class__.next_id
        self.__class__.next_id += 1

class Process_Line():
    """
    Models a 4 machine processing line
    whith no queues between machines
    so a machine cannot send a finished product to the next machine
    until that machine has sent its work on
    sort of like a conveyor belt (no accumultions)
    """

    def __init__(self, env, hopper, out_queue):

        self.env = env
        self.hopper = hopper
        self.out_queue = out_queue

        # signals when a machine is ready to process a product
        # using containers as a semifore
        self.ready_flags = {}
        for i in range(2, 5):
            self.ready_flags[i] = simpy.Container(env, init=1, capacity=1)

        # start line for first product
        self.env.process(self.__process_line())
        

    def __process_line(self):

        # get a product for the line to work on from hopper and
        prod = yield self.hopper.get()

        # start machine 1 processing
        print(f'{self.env.now} prod: {prod.id} start at machine 1')

        yield self.env.timeout(1)
        print(f'{self.env.now} prod: {prod.id} done at machine 1')
        # done processing at machine 1

        # send prod to next machine when its avaialable
        yield self.ready_flags[2].get(1)
        
        # start processing of next product at machine 1
        # note no yield here so it runs concurrently with this process
        self.env.process(self.__process_line())

        # start machine 2 processing
        print(f'{self.env.now} prod: {prod.id} start at machine 2')
        yield self.env.timeout(1)
        print(f'{self.env.now} prod: {prod.id} done at machine 2')

        # done, start next machine and reset ready flag when next machine is available
        yield self.ready_flags[3].get(1)
        self.ready_flags[2].put(1)

        # start machine 3 processing
        print(f'{self.env.now} prod: {prod.id} start at machine 3')
        yield self.env.timeout(1.5)
        print(f'{self.env.now} prod: {prod.id} done at machine 3')

        # done start next machine and reset ready flag
        yield self.ready_flags[4].get(1)
        self.ready_flags[3].put(1)

        #start machine 4 processing
        print(f'{self.env.now} prod: {prod.id} start at machine 4')
        yield env.timeout(2)
        print(f'{self.env.now} prod: {prod.id} done at machine 4')

        # done done
        # kick out product to output queue
        self.out_queue.put(prod)
        self.ready_flags[4].put(1)

def gen_prods(env, in_queue):
    """
    create products and put into the hopper/in_queue
    """
    while True:
        in_queue.put(Prod())
        yield env.timeout(.9)

# boot up
env = simpy.Environment()

in_queue = simpy.Store(env)
out_queue = simpy.Store(env)

line =  Process_Line(env, in_queue, out_queue) #auto starts processing
env.process(gen_prods(env, in_queue))

env.run(20)


This is just a alternative to the first answer but I used resources for the semifores.  Note that the machine that makes the request for the resource is not the machine that releases the resource.  also note that each machine has its own process.  Having each machine have its own process can make modeling assembly line with forks much easier.
"""
simple assemble line with no queues between machines.
so if the last machine takes a long time it blocks the line from advancing

Programmer: Michael R. Gibbs
"""

import simpy

class Prod():
    """
    sipmple class with unque ids
    """
    next_id = 1
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = self.__class__.next_id
        self.__class__.next_id += 1

class Process_Line():
    """
    Models a 4 machine processing line
    whith no queues between machines
    so a machine cannot send a finished product to the next machine
    until that machine has sent its work on
    sort of like a conveyor belt (no accumultions)
    """

    def __init__(self, env, hopper, out_queue):

        self.env = env
        self.hopper = hopper
        self.out_queue = out_queue

        # signals when a machine is ready to process a product
        # using containers as a semifore
        self.machines = {}
        for i in range(2, 5):
            self.machines[i] = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=1)

        # start line for first product
        self.env.process(self.__machine_1_proc())
        

    def __machine_1_proc(self):
        while True:
            # get a product for the line to work on from hopper and
            prod = yield self.hopper.get()

            # start machine 1 processing
            print(f'{self.env.now} prod: {prod.id} start at machine 1')

            yield self.env.timeout(1)
            print(f'{self.env.now} prod: {prod.id} done at machine 1')
            # done processing at machine 1

            # wait till next machine is available
            req = self.machines[2].request()
            yield req
            
            # start processing at next machine
            # note no yield here, start the next machine, do not wait, and loop
            self.env.process(self.__machine_2_proc(prod, req))
        

    def __machine_2_proc(self, prod, req):

        # start machine 2 processing
        print(f'{self.env.now} prod: {prod.id} start at machine 2')
        yield self.env.timeout(1)
        print(f'{self.env.now} prod: {prod.id} done at machine 2')

        # done, wait till next machaine is available and start it
        next_req = self.machines[3].request()
        yield next_req
        self.env.process(self.__machine_3_proc(prod, next_req))

        # become available
        self.machines[2].release(req)

    def __machine_3_proc(self, prod, req):
        # start machine 3 processing
        print(f'{self.env.now} prod: {prod.id} start at machine 3')
        yield self.env.timeout(1.5)
        print(f'{self.env.now} prod: {prod.id} done at machine 3')

        # done, wait till next machaine is available and start it
        next_req = self.machines[4].request()
        yield next_req
        self.env.process(self.__machine_4_proc(prod, next_req))

        # become available
        self.machines[3].release(req)

    def __machine_4_proc(self, prod, req):
        # start machine 4 processing

        print(f'{self.env.now} prod: {prod.id} start at machine 4')
        yield self.env.timeout(2)
        print(f'{self.env.now} prod: {prod.id} done at machine 4')

        # done, done, put into output queue
        self.out_queue.put(prod)

        # become available
        self.machines[4].release(req)

 
def gen_prods(env, in_queue):
    """
    create products and put into the hopper/in_queue
    """
    while True:
        in_queue.put(Prod())
        yield env.timeout(.9)

# boot up
env = simpy.Environment()

in_queue = simpy.Store(env)
out_queue = simpy.Store(env)

line =  Process_Line(env, in_queue, out_queue) #auto starts processing
env.process(gen_prods(env, in_queue))

env.run(20)

